# "You haven't read the question" downvotes

Tags: discussion, downvotes

My answer below was downvoted almost instantaneously. I clicked submit, then as soon as the question had submitted on my screen I hit refresh to view the comments on the previous answer. In the time it took my page to refresh (a maximum of about 5 seconds, and almost certainly less) the answer received a downvote.

The answer isn't long, but I absolutely guarantee that it would take more than the time available to actually read the answer, I'm a fast reader and can't read that fast with any level of comprehension

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27821470/1080648

Is there anything we can do to prevent or mitigate this kind of downvoting, considering a user doesn't have to explain a downvote?

Comment: The downvote has since been removed.

Comment: So how short is too short?  There are plenty of posts that I can accurately evaluate in <5 seconds, even though there are others that I couldn't accurately evaluate in a full minute.  Would getting that downvote 10 seconds later have really changed anything?

Comment: Wild guess: the downvoter read your first line (*A* ***constructor function*** *would be a typical way to refer to it*), disagreed with the term and proceeded to immediately downvote. Later, when their frontal cortex had finished processing the information, they reverted their vote. In any case, there is no problem anymore, things like this can happen.

Comment: Scimonster, it has, but we have no idea why it's been removed either? Possibly because I highlighted it, but the fact remains that we've no idea. Although I see @Servy's point that it likely wouldn't change anything to force a ten second wait. Is there a reason we don't require people to justify downvotes?

Comment: @JonStory Yes, there are dozens of reasons why we don't force people to justify downvotes.

Comment: Fair enough, well Makoto's answer seems to be answering my question fairly well - although it's news to me that the nature of voting is meant to be arbitrary.

Comment: It most certainly isn't meant to be that way. And you're only interpreting it to be so.

Comment: Guys please, I'm not trying to complain here (I'll survive the loss of 2 reputation), just understand the nature of downvoting and the policing/justification of them. I'm trying to ask the question and increase understanding, not bitch about having my points taken away.

Comment: It'd be cool if we could also prevent or mitigate blind, daft upvoting.  But we can't.

Answer (score 7):

Since anyone can cast a vote for any reason at any time, there's really not much you can do to mitigate this sort of voting behavior.  They don't have to explain it, so it is again an arbitrary action that can be taken by them.

I note that the downvote had since been removed, so I don't see that anything *should* be done in this case.

Comment: I wasn't really asking for anything to be done in terms of removing the downvote or giving me back the repuation (I'm not precious enough about 2 reputation) - more about the general concept of a downvote without a good reason, or the fact that early downvotes likely encourage other downvotes

Comment: @JonStory You don't know that the downvote didn't have a good reason.  He may well have had a good reason for downvoting.  Or this specific example aside, there are plenty of votes cast in less than 5 seconds of posting that have good reason.

Comment: There are, it was more the timing that I questioned - hence the question. If the answer is that "We're willing to take the hit on a few (possibly) toxic downvotes on longer questions, in order to avoid inconveniencing most users", that's an answer in itself.